# Dismissing the keyboard upon clicking on the UIDatePicker

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I can't seem to dismiss the keyboard when the user click on a UITextField then clicks directly starts interacting with the UIDatePicker control.

I am using the following to dismiss the keyboard upon a tap:

```
// The following code will remove the keyboard when it is not editing...
var g = new UITapGestureRecognizer(() => View.EndEditing(true));
View.AddGestureRecognizer(g);
```

Can you please tell me how I can dismiss the keyboard when the user clicks on the UIDatePicker control to start adjusting the date?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `.ResignFirstResponder()` on the ui element. That should dismiss the keyboard.

[xamarin recipe example for keyboard dismissing](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/input/keyboards/dismiss_the_keyboard/)
[xamarin documentation explaining ResignFirstResponder](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_iOS/hello,_iOS_deepdive/#8.additional-concepts-introduced-in-phoneword)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var tap = new UITapGestureRecognizer ();
tap.AddTarget (() => this.View.EndEditing (true));
this.View.AddGestureRecognizer (tap);
tap.CancelsTouchesInView = false;
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still does not work.  I'll have to come up with an example and post it.